# Google Chrome options like sliding panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

I want to create a panels like Google Chrome options window. Is there any library avaliable to create such kind of sliding panels?

Example
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the jQuery toggle() function. When the link gets clicked you toggle a div showing the content you want to show.

More info [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/toggle).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI has an accordion widget.  There are others that just use jQuery, just do a Google search for "jQuery accordion".  [This page](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/jquery-accordion-menus-tutorials/) discusses 30(!) of them.

Answer (score 1):

U can start with [this script](http://developer.digitalaria.com/devguide/gama/en/gama/SlidingPanel_html5.php)
And then adapt and style it too look more like Chrome